# Determine whether running user is logged in from within Trusted IP Range (from Apex)

Tags: apex, security, authentication, session, ip-whitelisting

I am creating a Login Flow that invokes Apex to do some processing, and need to determine whether the running (logging-in) user is connecting from an IP address whitelisted in our org's Trusted IP Ranges (as defined in Setup > Network Access > Trusted IP Ranges).

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this with **Auth.SessionManagement** class methods.  The code below sets the `isTrustedIp` variable based on whether or not the running user's IP address is in the trusted ranges (as defined in Setup > Network Access > Trusted IP Ranges):

```java
        Boolean isTrustedIp = false;

        Map<String, String> sessionAttributes;
        try {
            sessionAttributes = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            isTrustedIp = false;
            // TODO handle unexpected error...
        }

        String sourceIp = sessionAttributes.get('SourceIp');
        if(sourceIp != null) {
            isTrustedIp = Auth.SessionManagement.inOrgNetworkRange(sourceIp);
        }

        // TODO do something with isTrustedIp...
```